# How can i paint something larger on a QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I intend to draw a long rectangle bar on a single QListWidgetItem and the code goes like:

```
QIcon icon(":/black.jpg");
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->addItem("");
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->item(0)->setIcon(icon);
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->setIconSize(QSize(500, 20));
```

where TimeLineDisplayer is a QListWidget.
The current problem is, there seems to be a limit to the width of the icon. So HOW can i draw a bar long enough on an item of a QListWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved by a rather primitive way:

```
QPixmap icon_pix = QPixmap(":/black.jpg");
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->addItem(0);
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->setIconSize(QSize(2000, 2000));
ui->TimeLineDisplayer->item(0)->setIcon(icon_pix.copy(QRect(0, 0, 500, 20)));
```

still not sure which sentence makes the real differnce, so do tell me about it if you have any idea.